# WEBApi Routing Questing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would build the following WEB Api:

1. `api/voyages [params]`

   - Returns a list of travel depending on the filter parameters [params]
2. `api/voyages/1234`

   - Returns the data of a specific trip (eg: *1234*)
3. `api/voyages/1234/itinerary`

   - Returns the details of the itinerary of a trip specidico (eg: *1234*)
4. `api/voyage/1234,6789/inventory [params]`

   - Returns the details of inventory more trips (*1234 and 6789*) eventually filtered by [params]
5. `api/voyages/1234,6789/cabin [params]`

   - Returns the list of cabins more trips (1234 and 6789), eventually filtered by [params]

Can you help me to to correctly configure the file **`WebApiConfig.cs, Global.asax.cs`** and the controller?

Thanks in advance

Davide

Answer (score 1):

With [AttributeRouting](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), there is no need to configure too much ;-)

for your controller, you simply add this :

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/voyages")]
    public class VoyagesController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        public HttpAction GetVoyage(id)
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:int}\itinerary")]
        public HttpAction GetVoyage(id)
        {

        }
    }
```